# Why does implicit conversion not work with PartialFunction

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicit, partialfunction

Say I define the following:

```
type Func1 = PartialFunction[Int, String]
case class A(f: Int => String)
implicit def toA(func: Func1): A = A(func(_))
```

Then I might want to use the implicit conversion thus:

```
val a: A = {
    case i: Int => i.toString
}
```

But this does now compile. However explicit use of the function is fine:

```
val a: A = toA({
    case i: Int => i.toString
})
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val f = {
  case i: Int => i.toString
}
```

doesn't compile either:

> missing parameter type for expanded function
>
> The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. ([SLS
> 8.5](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html#pattern-matching-anonymous-functions))
>
> Expected type was: `?`
>
> `val f = {`

[According](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.9/src/library/scala/PartialFunction.scala#L25-L27) to Scaladocs, working code is

```
val f: PartialFunction[Int, String] = {
  case i: Int => i.toString
}
```

If you want implicit conversion try

```
val a: A = {
  case i: Int => i.toString
} : PartialFunction[Int, String]
```